# Bi-directional value stream with ReactiveCocoa

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

Is it possible to setup bi-directional stream of values when binding between model value and a control?

E.g. I have a model that has a read-write boolean attribute. And I bind a `UISwitch` control to that value with the following code:

```
RAC(self.switch, on) = RACObserve(self.model, booleanProperty);
```

Is there a way to write a single line of code to setup a binding so that when switch state changes, the attribute value is updated too?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22237326

Comment: Thanks, I learned a new thing from it, but still seems no dice with single line solution .)